# sql to extraction xml form column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml-parsing

This is the sample of xml in my table column;

Table name `t005`, column name `ACTIVITYDETAIL`, data type `xml`.

Sample of xml

```
<root> 
   <Parameter> 
      <Param>SearcgBy</Param> 
      <Value>ALL</Value> 
   </Parameter>         
   <Parameter> 
      <Param>SearchText</Param> 
      <Value>SA</Value> 
   </Parameter>    
</root>
```

Now I want output as

```
Param                value
SearchBy               ALL
SearchText             SA
```

I tried so many ways and here is my last try.

```
SELECT 
    p.value('(./Parameter/node())[1]', 'VARCHAR(8000)') as firstName,
    p.value('(./Parameter/node())[2]', 'VARCHAR(8000)') as lastName
FROM 
    t005 
CROSS APPLY 
    ACTIVITYDETAIL.nodes('/root') t(p)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT 
      t.p.value('Param[1]','varchar(20)') as Param,
      t.p.value('Value[1]','varchar(20)') as Value
 FROM T005 CROSS APPLY ACTIVITYDETAIL.nodes('/root/Parameter') t(p)
```